# How to integrate the AppInvite in Android?

Tags: android, deep-linking, dynamic-linking

I want to integrate the Invite Functionality where a user can send a link(which is different for different user) to another user and user clicks and get some rewards.

I have tried the Myntra App and send the invitation link to my friend but I can't understand that the link created is like - https://mynt.to/somrandomstring.

Now I know that in order the App to open one must define it in the Android Manifest and with the host and scheme should like

```
<data android:host="mynt.to" android:scheme="http"/>
                <data android:host="mynt.to" android:scheme="https"/>
```

But I dig in the Myntra App and found out that there is no declaration like this above in Manifest File. They have used `host="myntra.com"`

I cant understand how the app is able to open even if the host is different.

I want to know how to create the Custom App Link like Myntra does.

Also, PhonePe also does the same the link is `https://phon.pe/somerandomstring` and many other apps.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out [Firebase Invites](https://firebase.google.com/docs/invites/) and this [Dynamic links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/) probably easiest way.